# Remove lines ending with a random format with regex or notepad+

Tags: php, regex

I've got a list of url with random ending string like that :

```
paris-chambre-double-classique-avec-option-petit-dejeuner-a-lhotel-trianon-rive-gauche-4-pour-2-personnes-8ae0676c-aba2-4cf2-9391-91096a247672
paris-chambre-double-standard-avec-petit-dejeuner-et-acces-spa-pour-2-personnes-a-lhotel-le-mareuil-4-f707b0fe-31cb-4507-b7b3-7b91695bff9c
villes-deurope-visite-des-plus-grands-monuments-et-acces-aux-activites-etou-transport-avec-un-pass-par-destination-6a04659b-62c4-4995-9d0f-5e473df520cd

paris-chambre-doubletriplequadruple-confort-avec-petit-dejeuner-a-lhotel-de-france-gare-de-lyon-pour-2-a-4-pers-404f5780-9818-4599-af6b-be53b85a8185
paris-chambre-double-standard-avec-pdj-et-croisiere-sur-la-seine-en-option-a-lhotel-prince-albert-lyon-bercy-pour-2-33d0b087-5701-4199-9d9c-147cca687263.html
```

Now i try since few day with regex to convert this line into :

```
/paris-chambre-double-classique-avec-option-petit-dejeuner-a-lhotel-trianon-rive-gauche-4-pour-2-personnes-8ae0676c-aba2-4cf2-9391-91096a247672

/paris-chambre-double-standard-avec-petit-dejeuner-et-acces-spa-pour-2-personnes-a-lhotel-le-mareuil-4-f707b0fe-31cb-4507-b7b3-7b91695bff9c
villes-deurope-visite-des-plus-grands-monuments-et-acces-aux-activites-etou-transport-avec-un-pass-par-destination-6a04659b-62c4-4995-9d0f-5e473df520cd.html

/paris-chambre-doubletriplequadruple-confort-avec-petit-dejeuner-a-lhotel-de-france-gare-de-lyon-pour-2-a-4-pers-404f5780-9818-4599-af6b-be53b85a8185
paris-chambre-double-standard-avec-pdj-et-croisiere-sur-la-seine-en-option-a-lhotel-prince-albert-lyon-bercy-pour-2-33d0b087-5701-4199-9d9c-147cca687263.html
```

The problem is the random string :

```
3d0b087-5701-4199-9d9c-147cca687263
33d0b087-5701-4199-9d9c-147cca687263
```

I need to remove this part without having the last - and add .html: and add a / beforeurl like that:

```
/paris-chambre-doubletriplequadruple-confort-avec-petit-dejeuner-a-lhotel-de-france-gare-de-lyon-pour-2-a-4-pers.html
```

paris-chambre-double-standard-avec-pdj-et-croisiere-sur-la-seine-en-option-a-lhotel-prince-albert-lyon-bercy-pour-2.html

Thanks for your help. Regex is running me crazy.

This is for a new Linux server, running MySQL 5, PHP 5 and Apache 2.

Comment: For your given examples, you could use [`-\w{7,8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12}`](https://regex101.com/r/7JboRw/1/), otherwise please elaborate on your rules for these strings.

Answer (score 1):

The lines appear to end with some sort of hash, which means it can only contain the letters `a` to `f` and digits.

To match this hash, you can use the following regex (it does include the initial dash):

```
\-[0-9a-f]{8}\-[0-9a-f]{4}\-[0-9a-f]{4}\-[0-9a-f]{4}\-[0-9a-f]{12}
```

[See here for an demo](https://regex101.com/r/9noyAe/1)

Once you have matched what you want to remove, you can replace it with the PHP [`preg_replace` function](https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace.php).

Answer (score 0):

You could use this pattern to capture into group part you want to keep `^(.+)(?:-[0-9a-zA-Z]+){5}$`

and replace pattern is `\\\1.html`

Explanation:

`^` - match beginning of a string

`(.+)` - capturing group: match one or more of any characters

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`-[0-9a-zA-Z]+` - match hyphen `-` literally, then any letter (lower or uppercase) or any digit one or more times

`{5}` - match `(?:-[0-9a-zA-Z]+)` exactly five times

`$` - match end of string

**Replace pattern**:

`\\` - `\` literally

`\1` - refers to first capturing group

`.html` - `.html` literally

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZBly6M/1)